# Export excel file using PHPExcel，take about 2 minutes，lead to 504

Tags: php, nginx

environment:php+nginx;
I use PHPExcel for export and import excel file,and this operation would take about two minutes for a big data size,which leading to 504 gateway timeout. 
And the nginx factcgi_connect/read/send_timeout is 30s;
Do not change nginx settings,how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Run the file generation process in "offline" batch mode. PayPal does this for some reports - you request the report, get immediate notification that it is in process and when it is done (typically a few seconds but could be much longer) the status page is updated and you get a notification email. Basic steps:

1. Create a new table of reports to be processed.
2. When a user requests a report, add it with a "new" status
3. Add a new process running as a cronjob (e.g., every 5 minutes) that changes the status to "processing", creates the report and then changes the status to "completed" and stores the report in an accessible location (e.g., filename based on the report table record id)
4. Add a status page to show users the status of their reports including a download link if "completed".

This is a bit of work, but PHP makes it easy because you can run identical code from the command line and as a web process.